# How to pass multiple parameters in where clause in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to pass two parameter from one query to another query or is in any way to combined to query in single query

********* First Query ***********************

select count(*) as totalBill, package_id from bill.bill_periods_premaintenance
group by package_id

********* Second Query ***********************
select billId, to_date as toDate, pkg  from (
(select max(pre_maintenance_performance_main_id) as peId, max(len) as billId, package_id as pkg
from (select pre_maintenance_performance_main_id, road_details_id, package_id,unnest(bill_period_ids_array) as len from inspection.pre_maintenance_performance_main) as t
group by package_id) as lastPe
inner join bill.bill_periods_premaintenance as bill on  lastPe.billId=bill.bill_period_id) as finalTbl

Need to pass `toDate` and `pkg` from Second Query. If this package_id not contain in second query then only passed pkg from first to third query.
Overall I need to all pkg and billcount.If bill not contains second tbl also

```
select count(*) as pending, package_id from bill.bill_periods_premaintenance 
where to_date between "toDate"  and  now() and package_id= "pkg" group by package_id
```

first table  bill_periods_premaintenance

billid     package_id    to_date
1              1         01-01-2020
2              1         02-01-2020
3              1         03-01-2020
4              1         04-01-2020
Second table pre_maintenance_performance_main

pkg_id          bill_period_ids_array
1               {1,2}

Based on max bill_period_ids_array need (2) to count after this period time. In this case I want following o/p
pkgId       totalCount
1             2
After billid 02 less then this billid  to_date <02-01-2020

Comment: Don't tag spam! Only tag the DBMS you're really using. The title says Postgres, so I removed the others.

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example]. Add the `CREATE` statements of the tables and `INSERT` statements for some sample data. Add the desired result with that sample data as tabular text. Only paste **plain text**, **no** screenshots or other images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [WITH](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) keyword. This lets you write queries one after the other, where each query can use previous results. Something like this:

```sql
WITH t AS (
    SELECT pre_maintenance_performance_main_id, road_details_id, package_id, unnest(bill_period_ids_array) as len
    FROM inspection.pre_maintenance_performance_main
), 
lastPe AS (
    SELECT max(pre_maintenance_performance_main_id) as peId, max(len) as billId, package_id as pkg
    FROM t 
    GROUP BY package_id
),
finalTbl AS (
    SELECT billId, to_date as toDate, pkg
    FROM lastPe 
    INNER JOIN bill.bill_periods_premaintenance as bill ON lastPe.billId = bill.bill_period_id
)
SELECT count(*) as pending, package_id 
FROM bill.bill_periods_premaintenance, finalTbl 
WHERE to_date between finalTbl.toDate and  now() 
AND package_id = finalTbl.pkg
GROUP BY package_id;
```

Comment: Means how to combined with my example

Comment: I also need all data from bill_periods_premaintenance table but not in inspection.pre_maintenance_performance_main table with package_id  and null count. How is it possible?

Comment: This query return match records only. I need both match and unmatched data with count.

Comment: @Sudip the question was about passing multiple parameters between queries. If you have a different explicit question, consider creating a new question for it.

Comment: Your answer fine for my problem something I modify my extra requirement but Thank you so much.